# Choosing a cross-platform graphics library for perfect text rendering

Tags: user-interface, opengl, cross-platform, sdl, cairo

I want to write a simple text editing application in c/c++ ( mainly devoted to source code editing ) with these specifications:

- cross-platform ( Windows, OS X, Linux )
- with the as much as possible the same appearence on each os
- insanely fast
- a superior font printing quality *** MOST IMPORTANT OF ALL ***
- it's not very important the widget support, I don't really need a complex support of widget
- precedence to software code architecture and its speed instead of speed coming from support of hardware acceleration

Before writing I made a study and some search on the net, but I need some advice to choose better:

- GTK+ and wxwidgets: complete set of libraries to complete my task
- SDL: offers a virtualization layer over platform, so I can write platform independend graphics using SDL primitives
- Cairo ( or pango ):
- Skia
- views ( use inside chromium http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromeviews)
- AGG ( anti grain geometry: it seems the best text rendering library with its subpixel feature, but what about the speed and the support? )
- fog-framework ( http://code.google.com/p/fog/ ): seems good too, but misses some functionalities
- open GL
- scintilla

I discarded QT, I don't like how to use it.

Which things I miss using a library instead of another?
And what about the support?
In some cases, it's not very clear to me what each library offers to me and what is the work I have to do to reach my goal ( eg. other layers to add to graphics project ).

An example of graphic stack organization helps me very much too choose the right tool.
I have to choose the right balance to customization and deploy speed.
Eg: what SDL offers less than Cairo or Skia? Etc.
Eg. ( starting from layers closer to the OS )

- Backend ( = virtualization of the OS graphics )
- ?
- ?
- ?
- Rapid Application Toolkit to compose widgets into application

Comment: Hello, and again welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Questions asking for advice on choosing an API or library are not allowed here. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my mistake. Can you suggest me where I can ask this question?

Comment: What did you end up doing?